# How to mock client inside paymentintent for Stripe?

Tags: unit-testing, go, stripe-payments

Currently we are using `paymentintent.New()` method to create a payment intent for stripe but the issue we are facing is in writing unit tests (for integration test, we are already aware of stripe-mock)

Inside this method, a http client is created internally. Not sure how can we mock it.
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/master/paymentintent/client.go#L24

We have tried generating the mock of stripe http client by ourselves but that won't help much since paymentintent internally creates a HTTP client and we don't see a way to pass our own http client inside the paymentintent method

Answer (score 0):

`stripe-go` is using `stripe-mock` internally for unit testing. You can see this piece of [code](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-go/blob/master/testing/testing.go#L98) to learn how to set a mock server for you unit tests.